# 3000 mg/L NH4-N solution, pH 7.8

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Can anyone suggest a protocol for preparing 1 Litre ammoniacal solution (pH 7.8, NH4-N, 3000 mg/L) from NH4Cl and NaOH? 
I have worked out that I need 10.7g NH4CL and 0.45 g NaOH -is this correct? I am assuming that 1st step is to prepare 0.45 g NaoH in 0.5 L distilled water and then to that add 10.7 g NH4CL solution in 0.5 L of  distilled water.Total volume is 1 L?
Or are there better methods?

Comment: You say you want "(pH 7.8, NH4-N, 3000 mg/L) from NH4Cl and NaOH" what does the "3000 mg/L" mean?!? Is that the total mass of NH4Cl and NaOH?